# Excel VBA - Copy from one sheet into another > copies only one row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with my code. The code should copy all rows till the last row based on the sheet "hideMaster" column B, but this macro only copies the first 5 rows.

```
Sub DeleteFilterAndCopy()

Dim LASSSST As Long
Dim IP As Worksheet

Set IP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

LASSSST = IP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Rows.Count

Sheets("MASTER").Cells.clearcontents
Sheets("hideMASTER").Range("A5:U" & LASSSST).Copy
Sheets("MASTER").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

[...]
```

Can somebody find the problem here?

Comment: modify your `LASSSST = IP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Rows.Count` to `LASSSST = IP.Cells(IP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Rows.Count
`

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the answer :). But it does the same. It only pastes 5 rows.

Comment: you are checking **Column B** for last row ? does this column contain all data ? later on you are copying data from **Column A**, also, you are checking LastRow in Sheets "Input" but copying the range from Sheet "hideMASTER" ???

Comment: A containts a function that goes down till the last row of the sheet. B contains the right amount of data so I want to use this column to make sure it only copies relevant rows.

Comment: Input is the sheet I want the rows count from. hideMaster is the sheet i want to copy from (based on the rows count of input). Master is the sheet I want to paste the data in.

Comment: Should be `LASSSST = IP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: This is where stepping through your code with [F8] and setting a Watch on `LASSSST` would have helped.

Comment: WORKS @ Jeeped. I didn't now that (F8 trick/help), thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LASSSST = IP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Rows.Count
```

this is the number of rows in

```
IP.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
```

which is 1, since it's only one cell. This caused it to copy `"A5:U1"`

Use

```
IP.Cells(IP.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
```

Note that I included `IP.Rows.Count` instead of `Rows.Count` as Shai Rado suggested, however the number of rows is the same on every sheet so it wouldn't matter. It's still good practice to reference everything though.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: arcadeprecinct found the error.

Try this instead:

```
Sub DeleteFilterAndCopy()

Dim LASSSST As Long
Dim IP As Worksheet

Set IP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")

Sheets("MASTER").Cells.clearcontents
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("hideMASTER")
    .Range("A5", .Cells(Rows.Count,21).End(xlUp)).Copy Destination:= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MASTER").Range("A1")
End with
```

Comment: thanks! I'll test this code. Looks a bit better than mine ;)